# Realtime updating MDB database through a datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, real-time-updates

I am currently trying to create a small program that takes the data from a MDB database that is displayed in a datagridview. The program should allow the user to modify (add, update, delete) the data in the datagridview. Furthermore everything should be updated to the MDB automatically (no buttons). I know there are a lot of topics out there regarding this subject, however for some reason I am unable to reproduce the same results.

I am able to retrieve the data from the MDB file and display it in the datagridview but I am unable to add, modify or delete data. The program keeps throwing exceptions at me but I don't understand why.

First the user has to create a database. The database is generated automatically by code.

```
private void CreateNewDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DB_FILENAME = "c:\Test.mdb";

    // GENERATE THE ACCESS FILES, ITS TABLES AND ITS COLUMNS

    var cnnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.;Data Source=" + DB_FILENAME; //Use a late bound COM object to create a new catalog. This is so we avoid an interop assembly
    var catType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ADOX.Catalog");
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(catType);
    catType.InvokeMember("Create", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, new object[] { cnnStr });
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
    cnn.Open();
    var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();

    // CREATE SCHEDULE TABLE
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE ([ID] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Day] TEXT, [Month] TEXT, [Year] TEXT, [IMS] TEXT, [Customer] TEXT, [Short Description] TEXT, [Long Description] TEXT, [Delivery Ticket Number] TEXT, [Returned] TEXT)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SCHEDULE ([ID]) VALUES (1)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // DISPOSE OF THE VARIABLES USED
    cnn.Close();
    cnn.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();

}
```

Once the database has been created it is used in a windows form with a datagridview in it.

```
public void Initialize()
{

    Con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sttngs.DBloc);
    Con.Open();

    // TRY TO OPEN THE DATABASE FILE AND POPULATE THE DATAGRIDVIEW
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Day], [Month], [Year], [IMS], [Customer], [Short Description], [Long Description], [Delivery Ticket Number], [Returned] FROM SCHEDULE",Con); // WHERE [Returned] = '" + "NO' ", Con);

    // POPULATE cBuilder
    cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
    ScheduleData = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ScheduleData);

    if (ScheduleData.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       BindingSource BDS = new BindingSource();
       BDS.DataSource = ScheduleData;
       this.dataGridView.DataSource = BDS;        
    }
}
```

Once the data in the datagridview is changed (handled by the CellValidating event) the data should be updated in the MDB.

```
 private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (ScheduleData.GetChanges() != null)
     {
        dataGridView.EndEdit();
        da.Update(ScheduleData);
        ScheduleData.AcceptChanges();
     }
 }
```

The code is pretty straight forward but for some reason I am unable to figure out why the data in the MDB is not updated. I have been stuck for a while now so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see that will cause an issue is that when you setup your commandbuilder you are not requesting the relevant UPDATE, DELETE & INSERT commands.

When you generate the command builder like this :-

```
cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
```

Follow up with :-

```
cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
cBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
cBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
```

You may need to declare all of this in Cell Validating, I'm unsure. Give It a try.

Look this MSDN article over, its for the SQLcommamdbuilder, but the same rules apply :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

Also, You have no open connection to the Data Adapter as you try to update it :-

```
if (ScheduleData.GetChanges() != null)
     {
        dataGridView.EndEdit();

        //Open a connection Here
        da.Update(ScheduleData);

        ScheduleData.AcceptChanges();
     }
```

Your SQL String is incorrect, try :-

```
"SELECT (Day, Month, Year, IMS, Customer, Short Description, Long Description, Delivery Ticket Number, Returned) FROM [SCHEDULE]"
```

Comment: Derek, my connection is open because I made it public. It is opened inside the initialize procedure and closed when the form closes.

Comment: I also tried to implement the update,insert and delete commands but this still doesn't seem to work. It just crashes and says that it is unable to perform the update syntax. Any other suggestions?